# Cast is invalid on object

Tags: c#, solidworksapi, solidworkspdmapi

I have this problem, when I try to cast the "batch" object, I am raised exception "Invalid cast".
Can you help me out with why?
The vault5 object exists and is correct.

```
public void batch(IEdmVault5 vault5)
{
    edmVault11 = (IEdmVault11)vault5;
    IEdmBatchRefVars batch = default(IEdmBatchRefVars);
    batch = (IEdmBatchRefVars)edmVault11.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_BatchRefVars);

    //some code
}
```

Edit 1:
Error message:

> System.InvalidCastException
>         HResult=0x80004002
>         Messaggio=Cast specificato non valido

Comment: No, not from the code you provide. We have no idea what library you are using there and what the correct type would be. Check the declaration of `CreateUtility` to see what type it returns. Or use the debugger, if the type is dependent on the argument (as it looks like).

Comment: Also note that it's preferable to declare and initialize a variable to a useful value in a single step: `IEdmBatchRefVars batch = (IEdmBatchRefVars)edmVault11.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_BatchRefVars);`. There's no point in initializing it to `default(IEdmBatchRefVars)` and then immediately assigning a new value to it.

Comment: @PMF , this is Solidworks ePDM API a sample can be reference here https://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/epdmapi/Vault_Utilities_Example_CSharp.htm

Comment: Your vault might be null but there is other issues with your code that we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today. The solution was to initialize COM for the current thread in STA mode.

- For a WinForms app, this is already done for the main/UI thread (so that probably does not apply).
- For a console app, consider adding [STAThread] to your Main() method.
- If you're running this on background threads or tasks, you'll need to manipulate the thread state directly.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you try out this change , also

```
 public void batch(IEdmVault5 vault5)
{
    IEdmVault7 edmValult11 = null;
    if (vault5 == null)
    {
           vault5 = new EdmVault5();
    }
    edmVault11 = (IEdmVault11)vault5;
    IEdmBatchRefVars batch = default(IEdmBatchRefVars);
    batch = (IEdmBatchRefVars)edmVault11.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_BatchRefVars);

    //some code
}
```

Besides given the nature of Solidworks API make sure that the installation and license are valid .

Comment: thank you for your answer, I had tried to verify if the object was different from null, unfortunately the probelma remains.

Comment: Casting a null reference to any reference type won't give an `InvalidCastException`. If `vault5` were null, the OP would see a `NullReferenceException` instead (unless `CreateUtility` is an extension method).